# What does it mean for a One-to-many Link relation to be Unique?

Tags: visual-studio, linq, linq-to-sql, orm

i drug a line between two tables in the Linq Object Relational (O/R) mapper:

```
 Order                  Customer
--------------           ---------------
| OrderID    |           | CustomerID  |
| CustomerID |♦---------˃| ...         |
|            |           |             |
--------------           ---------------
```

**Note:** Or perhaps it was

```
 Order                    Customer
--------------           ---------------
| OrderID    |           | CustomerID  |
| CustomerID |˂---------♦| ...         |
| ...        |           |             |
--------------           ---------------
```

i'm not sure; it lets me drag both ways.

- First question, what's the arrowhead, and what's the diamond?

Assuming the second diagram, the *cardinality* of the `Association` was created as `OneToMany`. This makes sense, since:

- **one** customer
- has **many** orders

But what confuses me is the `Association.Unique` (Boolean) property. It defaults to `false`. This makes sense because it's a **OneToMany** association. `Order.CustomerID` cannot be unique, otherwise it wouldn't be a **OneToMany** association, it would be **OneToOne**.

But then i'm allowed to change the *OneToMany* Unique property to **true**. This makes no sense, so i conclude that `Unique` ness doesn't apply to `Order.CustomerID`, but instead to `Customer.CustomerID`. But the diagram already indicates `Customer.CustomerID` is a **Primary Key**. Of course it's unique, it's a primary key.

But the `Unique` property isn't set. This makes no sense, so i conclude that `Unique` ness doesn't mean either table.

- Second question, what does `Unique` mean?

  > *Specifies whether the foreign target columns have a uniqueness constraint*
- Third question: What is **parent** and **child**?

Assuming, again, the second diagram:

```
Customers.CustomerID ♦------------> Orders.CustomerID
```

i take `Customers` table to be a parent. It's the one who owns what it means to be a *customer*. You want to change something about a customer, you walk to the parent.

Meanwhile, the child `Orders` table comes along and wants to reference a `Customer`.

```
     Parent(diamond)                     Child(arrowhead)
====================                     =================
Customers.CustomerID (PK) ♦------------> Orders.CustomerID (FK)
```

Except that when i look at the association's **Parent** and **Child** properties:

**Child property**

- `Name`: `Orders`

**Parent property**

- `Name`: `Customer`

They want to create a property on the *"child"* called `Orders`. No, no, no. The child *is* orders. And they want to add a property to the parent called `Customer`. No, no no. The parent *is* a customer.

That means i must have it backwards, and the terms *parent* and *child* are the exact opposite of what i thought:

```
      Child(diamond)                     Parent(arrowhead)
====================                     =================
Customers.CustomerID (PK) ♦------------> Orders.CustomerID (FK)
```

And by this time i want to blow my brains out; and instead spend 35 minutes authoring a question on Stackoverflow; rather than continuing to scream at my computer.

Help.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding question 2 - The Unique property probably signifies that the relation is a OneToOne relation.

Even directly in a sql database there is no specific OneToOne relationship. Rather there is simply the foreign key where a key in one table can be exported to another table. As such a foreign key relationship is ALWAYS one to many. Using additional constraints on the table containing the exported key, the relationship can be made de facto one to one. But doing that doesn't change the foreign key relation, rather it simply applies additional conditions on the data in the foreign key table.

Regarding question 3: The property names mean that the child object (Order) will have a property called Customer which can be used to get an instance of the parent object. And the parent object will have a property called Orders which can be used to fetch children for the customer.